# Need JavaScript/Regex to pick out and process URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

"blah blah blah yada yada http://www.example.com/check?x=rabP4F3Mk&dept=check blah blah blah ..."

For example strings similar to the above, I need Regex/**JavaScript** code that returns a string like this: "rabP4F3Mk&dept=check"

I will *try* to be more precise:

```
if (the string contains "example.com/check?x="){ 
   return the portion of the token that contains "example.com/check?x=" after the "="
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matches = str.match(/example.com\/check\?x\=([^\s]*)/);
if(matches.length > 1) return matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"example.com/check?x=asdfasdf".match(/check\?x=(.*)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/example\.com\/check\?x=([^\s]+)/
```